# Can I user Microsoft Bot Builder in an app without Microsoft app ID?

Tags: botframework

I read about the Microsoft bot builder, seems pretty nice to me. 
But I am thinking about one thing.

It requires Microsoft app id and password to make it a rest endpoint.
The "chatconnector" seems connecting users and bot builder, creating a connection for each user.
if this is true, why it needs Microsoft app id and password?

```
  // Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
    var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
     appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
     appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
    });
```

If I disconnect the internet, I got a warning. This is what happened in emulator. I am not what will happen inside an app or a website.

```
 WARN: ChatConnector: receive - emulator running without security enabled.
```

But everything is still working.

1.What does chatconnector do exactly?

2.Is it possible to use it in a website without having Microsoft app id and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the emulator without the app id and pw.  They will be required for any other channel.  The connector service needs these credentials to do auth for the client, [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart).  It is used to send and receive messages as well which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-concepts) is a good place to learn about this and other key concepts.  Good Luck!